# Executing script after error

Tags: shell, shell-script

I want to continue execution of shell script even after error in particular step, but it is getting terminated after error

```
if [ condition ];then
     cmd
else 
     cmd1
     return 4
fi

cmd2
```

I want to have return code of 4 and execute the cmd2 even above step is not executed which is not happening. whole code is inside a function

Answer (score 0):

Although bash has a `return` statement, the only thing you can get with it is the function's exit status (a value between 0 and 255). So `return` is not what you want.

If you replace your `return` statement with an `echo`, you can capture the value and proceed further.

Rather you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
function master ()
{
    function check () 
    {
        if [ 1 == 2 ];then
            echo "Cmd1"
        else
            # Execute your command here
            echo 4
        fi
    }
    val=$(check)
    echo "Value: $val"
    echo "Done"
}
master
```

Note: I put your whole code inside a `master` function (to be in-line with your current script)

Comment: is function inside function supported ? I'm getting error

Comment: What's the error ?

Answer (score 0):

return on a function quit this function with the following number you specified (or the return code of the previous command executed) so it is a normal behaviour to quit without executing the next command (cmd2).
If you want to execute the command cmd2 but also return 4 at the end of the function because you use cmd1 and not cmd, use a flag for example:

```
flag=0
if [ condition ];then
     cmd
else 
     cmd1
     flag=1
fi
cmd2
if [[ $flag -eq 1 ]]; then
     return 4
fi
return 0
```

But it seems a little bit tricky and you should think of another way to do this (two distinct functions ?)